# When updating a view in another assembly, the page doesn't reflect my change

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I'm using the new Razor SDK (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor) to host my controllers and views in a different assembly.

```
> dotnet --version
2.1.300-rc1-008673
```

When I make changes to Razor views (*.cshtml) in a regular ASP.NET Core application and refresh the page, the page reflects my change.

However, when I do the same thing with a view in my other assembly, the page doesn't reflect my change.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you making the changes while debugging or in a hosted site?

Comment: @Brad: This happens while debugging.